# how to to store Multipale data in QR code using laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.6

I am working on **QR Code**. I want to store ( `name ,fname ,address`). I want to store this  3 data in QR Code.
But now I am able to store only one data. I am not able to add other 2. 
How to solve this problem?

**QR controller**

```
public function view_downlads($id)
{
    $view_qr = Student::where('student_certificate_approval','APPROVED')->find($id);
    $pdf = PDF::loadView('Admin.View_qr', compact('view_qr'))->setPaper('a4', 'landscape');
    return $pdf->stream('fileName' . '.pdf');
}
```

**view page code**

```
<img height="115" width="115" src="data:image/png;base64,{{DNS2D::getBarcodePNG($view_qr->name,'QRCODE')}}" alt="barcode" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method expects a string as a parameter. If all three attributes of your variable are strings you can concatenate them with a point:

```
<img height="115" width="115" src="data:image/png;base64,{{ DNS2D::getBarcodePNG($view_qr->name.$view_qr->fname.$view_qr->address,'QRCODE') }}" alt="barcode" />
```

If you want to leave a space between each data, just concatenate a string with a space between them:

```
<img height="115" width="115" src="data:image/png;base64,{{ DNS2D::getBarcodePNG($view_qr->name.' '.$view_qr->fname.' '.$view_qr->address,'QRCODE') }}" alt="barcode" />
```

Comment: working perfect thank you , is there possible to maintain space in each data

Comment: yes, sure, just concatenate a string with a space between them  `DNS2D::getBarcodePNG($view_qr->name.' '.$view_qr->fname.' '.$view_qr->address,'QRCODE')`

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple values to be stored in QR Code such as Name, Fname, Address, etc.

So all this information must be included in the QR Code in a readable format, so can use JSON for storing your infomation.

Here is what you have to do :

```
//Your data goes here
$arrData = [
    'Name'  => $yourName,
    'Fname' => $yourFname,
    'Address' => $yourAddress,
    /* Add here all the data you need*/
];

//Json encode your data
$jsonData = json_encode($arrData);
```

use the `$jsonData` to write into the QR Code. When you are reading the QR Code retrive the data from the json data :

```
//json decode the QR Code value 
$arrData = json_decode($readedQRCodeData, true);
```

The `$arrData` will be then

```
// array (
// 'Name' => 'yourname',
// 'Fname' => 'yourfname',
// 'Address'=>'yourAddress'
//)
```

Then your HTML will be like:

```
<img height="115" width="115" src="data:image/png;base64,{{ DNS2D::getBarcodePNG($jsonData,'QRCODE') }}" alt="barcode" />
```